Row reducing binary matrix
I'm trying to understand https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BCH_code#Decoding_examples
I'm now having trouble with the row reduction in binary below ,
with elements from $GF(2^4)$ in binary :
$s_1=1011 , _2 = 1001 , _3 = 1011 , _4 = 1101 , s_{5}=0001,  s_{6}=1001. $

Next, apply the Peterson procedure by row-reducing the following
augmented matrix. ${\displaystyle \left[S_{3\times 3}|C_{3\times
 1}\right]={\begin{bmatrix}s_{1}&s_{2}&s_{3}&s_{4}\\s_{2}&s_{3}&s_{4}&s_{5}\\s_{3}&s_{4}&s_{5}&s_{6}\end{bmatrix}}={\begin{bmatrix}1011&1001&1011&1101\\1001&1011&1101&0001\\1011&1101&0001&1001\end{bmatrix}}\Rightarrow
 {\begin{bmatrix}0001&0000&1000&0111\\0000&0001&1011&0001\\0000&0000&0000&0000\end{bmatrix}}}$

Could someone show me which steps were used (row substitution, addition or multiplication ) to get the all 0 row ?

The Wikipedia description is terrrible to say the least. The row-reduction should be done in GF$(2^4)$ arithmetic, so that when (in the process of Gaussian elimination) you subtract a multiple of the first row from the second, you are subtracting $\frac{s_2}{s_1}[s_1 \quad s_2\quad s_3\quad s_4] = [s_2\quad \cdots ] $ from $[s_2\quad s_3\quad s_4\quad s_5]$ where that computation is done in GF$(2^4)$  and not with 4-bit vectors.

@DilipSarwate -  those 4 bit vectors are a shorthand notation for a $GF(2^4)$ elements, $1011 = 1 x^3 + 0 x^2 + 1 x + 1$ . Note that the Peterson (PGZ) decoder has time complexity $O(n^3)$, while Berlekamp Massey and Sugiyama extended Euclidean decoders have time complexity $O(n^2)$.  The BCH article doesn't include Berlekamp Massey, but the Reed Solomon article does https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reed%E2%80%93Solomon_error_correction#BCH_view_decoders .

@rcgldr I fully understand what those 4-bit vectors are, and I stand by my assertion that the Wikipedia description is terrible.  The calculations needed go from the $3\times 4$ matrix of the known syndromes to the end result are $GF(2^4)$ calculations and not $GF(2)$ operations on the $3\times 16$ matrix shown to row-reduce it to the final form with with the last row being all zeroes. That last row is 4 zeroes in $GF(2^4)$, not 16 zeroes in $GF(2)$.

@DilipSarwate - the Wiki article explains its usage of binary via an example before using those binary values. $x^{9}+x^{4}+x^{2} = $ [ 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 ] .  Another case where using binary is helpful is when doing isomorphic mapping from one field to another via a matrix multiply by an n row by n bit matrix, where that multiply is done in $GF(2)$ and not $GF(2^n)$.

I am using the discrete logarithm table from my old Q&A pair prepared for referrals like this. What your source calls $\alpha$ is what I call $\gamma$, so for example
$$1011=\gamma^3+\gamma+1=\gamma^7,\quad 1001=\gamma^3+1=\gamma^{14},\quad 1101=\gamma^3+\gamma^2+1=\gamma^{13}$
$$
et cetera. My table is always used in the last step. See the comment by @rcgldr under the question for information about how to interpret the bit strings, except that I use $\gamma$ instead of $x$, because I reserve $x$ for an indeterminate (and hence replace it with something else when I move to a quotient field of a polynomial ring).
Anyway, in terms of powers of $\gamma$s the $S$-matrix reads
$$
S=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
\gamma^7& \gamma^{14}& \gamma^7&\gamma^{13}\\
\gamma^{14}& \gamma^7&\gamma^{13}&1\\
\gamma^7&\gamma^{13}&1&\gamma^{14}
\end{array}\right).
$$
So, pivoting the first column, we add the top row multiplied by $\gamma^7$ to the second, and simply also add the top row to the bottom row. This yields (again consult the table)
$$
S\to \left(\begin{array}{cccc}
\gamma^7& \gamma^{14}& \gamma^7&\gamma^{13}\\
0& \gamma^{10}&\gamma^{2}&\gamma^{10}\\
0&\gamma^{2}&\gamma^9&\gamma^{2}
\end{array}\right).
$$
As $\gamma^{15}=1$ we have $\gamma^2=\gamma^{17}$, and can immediately tell
that the bottom row is gotten from the second when divided by $\gamma^8$. In other words, the two last rows are scalar multiples of each other, and the row reduction step produces an all zeros row when pivoting the second column.

One issue with using $\gamma$ is cases where knowing if a sum = 0 is needed. For example in $GF(2^4)$, while it is obvious that $\gamma^7+\gamma^7 = 0$, it won't be obvious that $\gamma^4+\gamma^9+\gamma^{14} = 0$, but if using binary representation, it would be obvious. Another situation where using binary is better would be isomorphic mapping of $GF(2^n)$ to another field using a $n$ row by $n$ bit column matrix, where the multiply is  done in $GF(2)$ and not $GF(2^n$).

Point taken @rcgldr. My reasons for sticking to $\gamma,\beta,\alpha$,whatnot are, in addition to 0) personal inertia, 1) having a reminder about the underlying multiplication rules (totally hidden when using bit strings), 2) avoiding the use of $x$, bound to lead to confusion, 3) making it easier to distuingish elements of $GF(2^n)$ from those of $GF(2^m)$, $m\neq n$, where bitstrings make some users think that, e.g. zero padding does not change the element, and 4) in the case of "small" fields (say up to $2^{14}$) my own implementations use discrete logarithm tables exclusively.

(cont'd) Of course, in some contexts item 3 is not pressing, and item 4 is not relevant either for larger fields. All depending :-)

If storing values as powers of $\gamma$, wouldn't addition tables also be needed, and wouldn't these be $2^n$ by $2^n$? If values are stored in binary, addition or subtraction is just XOR, and multiplication would involve 2 log table lookups, 1 ADD, then 1 exp table lookup. On systems with carryless multiply, such as PCLMULQDQ on X86, then $GF(2^n)$ multiply is implemented with 3 carryless multiplies and 1 XOR, for $n$ up to 64. Hardware implementations are almost always binary.

@rcgldr My implementations used (past tense, talking the last years of DOS era here) a discrete log table, and an a inverse table. Storage was binary (or monomial basis form). Exactly to make addition = XOR. Multiplication was, indeed, modular addition and table look ups. Here I used exponential form, because space usage is then uniform. Admittedly binary would do that as well, didn't think about it, really. I have this DLT mostly memorized, and using it is thus simple. Don't necessarily recommend doing it at home this way :-)

I forgot to mention, for larger fields like $GF(2^{64})$, you can't use log | exp tables, and I'm not aware of a practical way to map to something like $GF((2^{32})^2)$, which might help for finding inverse, but an inverse can be found by using exponentiation by squaring for $a^{2^{64-2}} = 1/a$, and multiply implemented using a carryless multiply instruction.

@rcgldr I would have paid extra to have PC with a carryless multiply instruction in its assembler instruction set :-)
